# Excel VBA single message box for all empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to return the "titles" of the cells and not the address of all cells that are empty in the range below, or in the form below aswell.
I would like to display a single message box listing all the returned titles of the cells (I gave the titles above the cells) if there are any.

So, instead of `Range("C17, E23")`, I'd like to show the title of the cell.
Example:
Range ("C17") = "Nome/Razão Social"
Range ("E23") = "Celular"

Range and title of the cells: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Gms.jpg

Code run perfect, but I'd like to improve like I said above.

Code running: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0qZs.jpg

Thanks!

```
Dim C As Range
Dim MsgStr As String
Dim rng As Range


'Define which cell must not be empty in the range below
Set rng = Planilha4.Range("C17, E23")

'Check every cell in the range
For Each C In rng
    If C.Value2 = "" Then
        If MsgStr = "" Then
            MsgStr = C.Address(False, False)
        Else
            MsgStr = MsgStr & "," & C.Address(False, False)
        End If
    End If
Next C

Dim lLastComma As Long: lLastComma = InStrRev(MsgStr, ",")
If lLastComma > 0 Then: MsgStr = Left(MsgStr, lLastComma - 1) & Replace(MsgStr, ",", " and ", lLastComma, 1)
MsgBox MsgStr & " cell" & IIf(lLastComma > 0, "s are ", " is ") & "empty"

'MsgBox MsgStr & " cells are empty", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `C.Address` with `C.Offset(-1, 0).Value2` ?

Comment: @chrisneilsen only the first range worked, [link](https://imgur.com/a/MMdgtvb). But anyway, I'd rather declare the range with the name I want, instead of using offset. Any ideia? Thanks for now.

Comment: Did you make the change for _both_ uses of `C.Address`?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I didn't, I forgot the other one actually. But it worked! Great!
Another solution for this, like I said above, I'd rather to declare the range with the name I want, instead of using offset. Any ideia for that? Thanks!!

Comment: You might be able to use "Named Range" 's instead of addresses.  But there is still two cells involved for each field. You could could use two named cells for each field I suppose, but an Offset seems simpler to me.

Comment: Yes, but I've got other sheets with some much more cells instead of just two named. This was just for example. That's why I'd rather be declare them.
Can you tell me how should I do? Because what if I have 10 range? How should I write? Thanks.

Comment: @urdearboy thanks for the reply, how can I call them by name? I tried with 
`Worksheets.Names`, but I couldnt do it. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using " Named Range" 's.

Set up your names in the "Name Manager".  You could either use one Name for each field, and ensure the heading is always offset at a specific place (eg previous row, same column), or use two Names for each field (in which case the header can be anywhere - much more difficult to maintan in my opinion)

Better still, use a specific format for the Names so you don't have to manage the Fields in two places (Name Manager and Code)

I've used Names formatted as "Field#_Required".  Set up in Name Manager like this

[image]

Then this code will process all Workbook scoped Named Ranges looking for Names with the format "Field*_Required" that refer to a range on the specified sheet.  Headers are assumed to be in the same column, previous row.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim MsgStr As String
    Dim LastComma As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("YourForm")  ' set to the Form sheet

    ' Check every named range
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If nm.Name Like "Field*_Required" Then
            If nm.RefersToRange.Worksheet Is ws Then
                If IsEmpty(nm.RefersToRange.Value2) Then
                    MsgStr = MsgStr & ", " & nm.RefersToRange.Offset(-1, 0).Value2
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If MsgStr <> vbNullString Then
        MsgStr = Mid$(MsgStr, 3) ' strip leading ", "
        LastComma = InStrRev(MsgStr, ",")
        If LastComma > 0 Then
            MsgStr = Left$(MsgStr, LastComma - 1) & _
                     Replace$(MsgStr, ",", " and", LastComma, 1)
        End If
        MsgStr = MsgStr & " cell" & IIf(LastComma > 0, "s are", " is") & " empty"
        MsgBox MsgStr, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Missing Fields!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Almost did what I wanted!
The MsgBox still is showing name offset cell `MsgStr = MsgStr & ", " & nm.RefersToRange.Offset(-1, 0).Value2`, I also noticed that Name Manager must not contain any space, so the MsgBox would be something like "Field1_Required" instead of "Fiel 1 Required is empty" (it's more presentable for the client you know?).

That's what I wanted though, a beautiful message instead with underline in it.

Comment: I wrote it to use offset because _I_ believe that to be a better solution.   But as I said in my answer you could have two named ranges for each field.  Secondly, the message would show the text in the header cell, not the name given to the named range

Answer (score -1):

Named ranges aren't the solution here. You want to enter "E23" and return "Celular". That is a dictionary's job. If you don't want to set up a dictionary a simple array might do, like

```
Dim Dict(1,10) As Variant
Dict(0, 0) = "E23"
Dict(1, 0) = "Celular"
Dict(0, 1) = "C17"
Dict 1, 1) = [Whatever]
```

If `Dict` were a dictionary you could call "Celular" by the name of "E23". If it's an array, as above, you can use an Enum to define its position in the array by another name.

Edit Feb 10, 2019 ======================
I set up a worksheet called "Dict" [image: like this].

Now you can run code like below. Remember, however, that you need to set a reference to MS Scripting Runtime.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nda                                ' Dictionary array
    NdaAddress
    NdaCaption
    NdaCapCell
    NdaTip
End Enum

Sub CreateDict()
    ' https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

    Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim R As Long, C As Long
    Dim DictVal() As String

    Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Arr = Worksheets("Dict").Range("A2:E5").Value
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        ReDim DictVal(1 To UBound(Arr, 2) - 1)
        For C = 2 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            DictVal(C - 1) = Arr(R, C)
        Next C
'        Debug.Print Arr(R, 1), Join(DictVal, "|")
        Dict.Add Arr(R, 1), Join(DictVal, "|")
    Next R

    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In Dict.Keys
        Debug.Print Key,
        DictVal = Split(Dict(Key), "|")
        Debug.Print DictVal(NdaAddress), DictVal(NdaCaption), DictVal(NdaCapCell), DictVal(NdaTip)
    Next Key
End Sub
```

The idea is that the Key "Tel" will give you the address of the cell, the adress of the caption cell, the caption itself and a control tip. Add or reduce as desired/required. Consider using a small utility function to retrieve the part you want.

```
Debug.Print DictItem(Dict("Name"), NdaCaption)
Private Function DictItem(DictKey As String, _
                          Itm As Nda) As String
    DictItem = Split(DictKey, "|")(Itm)
End Function
```

Comment: It seems like your example must work it better! I made some research about dictionary (I've never use before), but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me please? How do I call them on the loop for example? Can you send me a code? Really thanks for the tips for now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was travelling. Now I have added some code to my answer which should help you on your way.

Comment: Great explanation! It's seem a little bit complicated about dict.
I printed the result, but it doesn't show only the "black field", and where should I put the Msgbox?
Also, I didn't understand the last part "Private Function". Just to register in this question and for me to learn, can you make an example with we use array instead of dict? Thanks for your time!!

Comment: It seems complicated because you didn't master it. The key is the Excel table where you keep the texts. This you need to fully understand! Next, run the proc CreateDict. Enable the line `Debug.Print Arr(R, 1), Join(DictVal, "|")` to help you understand what's being done. Observe that `Arr = Worksheets("Dict").Range("A2:E5").Value` creates an array which you might use directly. In my example it is used to feed into the dictionary.

Comment: Another key to understand my solution is that each dictionary's *Key*  has one "translation". In my solution the "translation" is an array which can have any number of values. I have given them numbers and then named the numbers (in the Enum). The utility function as the bottom returns the array element you specify. At the bottom of `CreateDict` there is a test printout. Replace `Debug.Print DictVal(NdaAddress), DictVal(NdaCaption)` etc with  `Debug.Print DictItem(Dict(Key), NdaAddress), DictItem(Dict(Key), NdaCaption)` for a demonstration.

Comment: I don't understand "only the black field". In your project you might reconfigure `CreateDict` as a function to return a the entire dictionary as a variable to your `Main` proc. You could then use the function `DictItem` to construct any MsgBox you want using the numbered elements.

Comment: Well, I couldn' do it. This method is too hard,omg!!
But the fact is, I need the msgbox to work with the name that I want to give, and not the range of it. And this solution you gave, I wasn't able to do it all by myself ):

Do you want me to send the sheet for example, or can you send me the code ready? PLEASE!!

Comment: The code that I have, it worked! But with the name of the range (not the way I want).

Comment: I think you made some headway and came to a new problem, perhaps implementation. Close this thread and start a new one from the position you are now at.

Comment: Really thanks for your time! But my question was exactly the same, there's not point to close this thread. I would like to make my MsgBox better, that's it. My code works, but I need help. Have a great week (: